# How to use PatchValue inside a loop on a FormArray?

Tags: angular, formarray

Hello everyone, I have a function where i pass the id when i use console.log(id)  it's working fine but why i can't use patchValue inside a loop in a formArray? i want all the first 5 elements to have the same id.

```
for(let j=0; j<5; j++)
{
  this.myarray.at(j).patchValue([
    {
       elementid: id
       
     }
   ]);
  
}
```

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any error ... but the elementId doesn't receive the id...

Comment: and if i use the same patchValue and not inside the loop and only for the first element it works

Comment: are you sure of your 'at' function? Stackblitz doesn't know it on Arrays. I looked it up and it seems to be an "experimental function": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you were trying to do, but I did a small [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhkudj?file=src/app/app.component.ts) where I replace the values within a loop using `splice`.
As you can see in the console, the first 5 elements of the array all have the same id after running the function, while the 'name' is unchanged.

There are probably better ways of achieving the same result though

Comment: After some other research i found this this.myarray.controls[j].get('elementid').setValue(id); it worked perfectly as well as your solution  thank you so much for your time i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.myarray.controls[j].get('elementid').setValue(id);
```